# Prove that $m(E)=0$.(Exercise 4.10 on rudin's real and complex analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem**  Let $n_{1}<n_{2}<n_{3}<\cdots$ be positive integers,and let $E$ be
>   the set of all $x\in [0,2\pi]$ atwhich $\{\sin n_{k}x\}$ converges. Prove that $m(E)=0$.

my try: I use the hint of rudin, first Let $ f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sin n_{k}x $ on $E$. From the relation $2\sin^{2}\alpha=1-\cos{2\alpha}$,we see that $2(f(x))^2=1-\lim_{k\to\infty}\cos 2n_{k}x$.and use Riemann-Lebesgue lemma,we have
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{E}\cos 2n_{k}x dx=0$$
and since $|\cos 2n_{k}x|\leq 1\in L^{1}(E)$,then use Lebgsgue dominated convergence theorem,we have
$$ 2\int_{E}f^2(x)dx=m(E) $$
Or
$$ \int_{E}\left(f^{2}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \right)dx=0 $$
Then I don't know how to going on...
also we have 
$$ \int_{E}f(x)dx=0 $$
in rudin's hint,it seems to prove that 
$$ f^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\qquad  \text{a.e  on} \quad E$$
but I don't know how to get that because we don't know $f^2(x)-\frac{1}{2}\geq 0$ or$f^2(x)-\frac{1}{2}\leq 0$ on $E$. Can anyone help me ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can do the same thing which you did for $E$ for any (measurable) subset $F \subset E$. Thus, you get
$$
\int_F f^2 (x) - \frac{1}{2}, \, dx = 0
$$
for every measurable subset $F \subset E$ (of finite measure). From this, it is not hard to see $f^2 = 1/2$ a.e. on $E$.

Comment: Ok,I See. Thank you very much :)